# Centos 8.2 KVM Windows Server 2019 Blue Screen

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, windows-server-2019, hypervisor, centos8

---

**EDIT 11.07.2020**

I prepared a custom vhd via virtualbox. It has the same bluescreen, but now I'm getting into cmd. mdsched worked fine -> So no memory issue...

---

Informations:

- HP Proliant 380 G9
- QEMU emulator version 2.12.0 (qemu-kvm-2.12.0-99.module_el8.2.0+385+c644c6e8.2)
- libvirt version: 4.5.0, package: 42.module_el8.2.0+320+13f867d7

Maschine-Config of Virtmanager

```
<domain type="kvm">
      <name>srvvmdc</name>
      <uuid>cadd396c-c953-454b-9a1b-445eb50037fe</uuid>
      <metadata>
        <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
          <libosinfo:os id="http://microsoft.com/win/2k16"/>
        </libosinfo:libosinfo>
      </metadata>
      <memory unit="KiB">8388608</memory>
      <currentMemory unit="KiB">8388608</currentMemory>
      <vcpu placement="static">6</vcpu>
      <os>
        <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-rhel7.6.0">hvm</type>
      </os>
      <features>
        <acpi/>
        <apic/>
        <hyperv>
          <relaxed state="on"/>
          <vapic state="on"/>
          <spinlocks state="on" retries="8191"/>
        </hyperv>
        <vmport state="off"/>
      </features>
      <cpu mode="host-model" check="partial">
        <model fallback="allow"/>
      </cpu>
      <clock offset="localtime">
        <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
        <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
        <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
        <timer name="hypervclock" present="yes"/>
      </clock>
      <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
      <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
      <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
      <pm>
        <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
        <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
      </pm>
      <devices>
        <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
        <disk type="file" device="disk">
          <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
          <source file="/home/administrator/VM/srvvmdc.qcow2"/>
          <target dev="sda" bus="sata"/>
          <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="0"/>
        </disk>
        <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
          <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
          <source file="/home/administrator/Downloads/17763.737.190906-2324.rs5_release_svc_refresh_SERVERESSENTIALS_OEM_x64FRE_de-de_1.iso"/>
          <target dev="sdb" bus="sata"/>
          <readonly/>
          <boot order="1"/>
          <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="1"/>
        </disk>
        <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
          <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
          <source file="/home/administrator/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.171.iso"/>
          <target dev="sdc" bus="sata"/>
          <readonly/>
          <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="2"/>
        </disk>
        <controller type="usb" index="0" model="qemu-xhci" ports="15">
          <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
        </controller>
        <controller type="sata" index="0">
          <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1f" function="0x2"/>
        </controller>
        <controller type="pci" index="0" model="pcie-root"/>
        <controller type="pci" index="1" model="pcie-root-port">
          <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
          <target chassis="1" port="0x10"/>
          <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
        </controller>
        <controller type="pci" index="2" model="pcie-root-port">
          <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
          <target chassis="2" port="0x11"/>
          <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x1"/>
        </controller>
        <controller type="pci" index="3" model="pcie-root-port">
          <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
          <target chassis="3" port="0x12"/>
          <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x2"/>
        </controller>
        <controller type="pci" index="4" model="pcie-root-port">
          <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
          <target chassis="4" port="0x13"/>
          <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x3"/>
        </controller>
        <controller type="pci" index="5" model="pcie-root-port">
          <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
          <target chassis="5" port="0x14"/>
          <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x4"/>
        </controller>
        <controller type="virtio-serial" index="0">
          <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x03" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
        </controller>
        <interface type="bridge">
          <mac address="52:54:00:68:cb:7c"/>
          <source bridge="bridge0"/>
          <model type="e1000e"/>
          <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
        </interface>
        <serial type="pty">
          <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
            <model name="isa-serial"/>
          </target>
        </serial>
        <console type="pty">
          <target type="serial" port="0"/>
        </console>
        <channel type="spicevmc">
          <target type="virtio" name="com.redhat.spice.0"/>
          <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>
        </channel>
        <input type="tablet" bus="usb">
          <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1"/>
        </input>
        <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
        <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
        <graphics type="spice" autoport="yes">
          <listen type="address"/>
          <image compression="off"/>
        </graphics>
        <sound model="ich9">
          <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1b" function="0x0"/>
        </sound>
        <video>
          <model type="qxl" ram="65536" vram="65536" vgamem="16384" heads="1" primary="yes"/>
          <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
        </video>
        <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
          <address type="usb" bus="0" port="2"/>
        </redirdev>
        <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
          <address type="usb" bus="0" port="3"/>
        </redirdev>
        <memballoon model="virtio">
          <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x04" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
        </memballoon>
      </devices>
    </domain>
```

The installation process works well:
[image]

But after installation and reboot:

[image]

Whats that?

**EDIT** 03.07.2020

Windows 10 Pro VM & Centos 8 VM working well...
Hardware was tested 2 days ago.

**EDIT** 03.07.2020

Log from the vm of qemu

> 2020-07-03 18:28:51.099+0000: starting up libvirt version: 4.5.0,
> package: 42.module_el8.2.0+320+13f867d7 (CentOS Buildsys
> bugs@centos.org, 2020-05-28-17:13:31, ), qemu version:
> 2.12.0qemu-kvm-2.12.0-99.module_el8.2.0+385+c644c6e8.2, kernel: 4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64, hostname: hypervisor.wulf.systems LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
> QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=spice /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -name
> guest=srvvmdc,debug-threads=on -S -object
> secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-5-srvvmdc/master-key.aes
> -machine pc-q35-rhel7.6.0,accel=kvm,usb=off,vmport=off,dump-guest-core=off -cpu
> Haswell-noTSX-IBRS,vme=on,ss=on,vmx=on,f16c=on,rdrand=on,hypervisor=on,arat=on,tsc-adjust=on,umip=on,md-clear=on,stibp=on,arch-capabilities=on,ssbd=on,xsaveopt=on,pdpe1gb=on,abm=on,ibpb=on,skip-l1dfl-vmentry=on,hv-time,hv-relaxed,hv-vapic,hv-spinlocks=0x1fff
> -m 8192 -realtime mlock=off -smp 6,sockets=6,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid cadd396c-c953-454b-9a1b-445eb50037fe -no-user-config -nodefaults
> -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,fd=31,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc
> base=localtime,driftfix=slew -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=delay
> -no-hpet -no-shutdown -global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1 -global ICH9-LPC.disable_s4=1 -boot strict=on -device
> pcie-root-port,port=0x10,chassis=1,id=pci.1,bus=pcie.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x2
> -device pcie-root-port,port=0x11,chassis=2,id=pci.2,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x1
> -device pcie-root-port,port=0x12,chassis=3,id=pci.3,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x2
> -device pcie-root-port,port=0x13,chassis=4,id=pci.4,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x3
> -device pcie-root-port,port=0x14,chassis=5,id=pci.5,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x4
> -device pcie-root-port,port=0x15,chassis=6,id=pci.6,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2.0x5
> -device qemu-xhci,p2=15,p3=15,id=usb,bus=pci.2,addr=0x0 -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi0,bus=pci.5,addr=0x0 -device
> virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.3,addr=0x0 -drive
> 'file=/home/administrator/Downloads/17763.737.190906-2324.rs5_release_svc_refresh_SERVERESSENTIALS_OEM_x64FRE_de-de_1(1).iso,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-sata0-0-1,media=cdrom,readonly=on'
> -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,drive=drive-sata0-0-1,id=sata0-0-1,bootindex=1 -drive
> file=/home/administrator/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.171.iso,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-sata0-0-2,media=cdrom,readonly=on
> -device ide-cd,bus=ide.2,drive=drive-sata0-0-2,id=sata0-0-2 -drive file=/home/administrator/VM/srvvmdc.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-scsi0-0-0-3
> -device scsi-hd,bus=scsi0.0,channel=0,scsi-id=0,lun=3,drive=drive-scsi0-0-0-3,id=scsi0-0-0-3
> -netdev tap,fd=33,id=hostnet0 -device e1000e,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:68:cb:7c,bus=pci.1,addr=0x0
> -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -chardev
> spicevmc,id=charchannel0,name=vdagent -device
> virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,id=channel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0
> -spice port=5902,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing,image-compression=off,seamless-migration=on -device qxl-vga,id=video0,ram_size=67108864,vram_size=67108864,vram64_size_mb=0,vgamem_mb=16,max_outputs=1,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1
> -device ich9-intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1b -device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 -chardev
> spicevmc,id=charredir0,name=usbredir -device
> usb-redir,chardev=charredir0,id=redir0,bus=usb.0,port=2 -chardev
> spicevmc,id=charredir1,name=usbredir -device
> usb-redir,chardev=charredir1,id=redir1,bus=usb.0,port=3 -device
> virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.4,addr=0x0 -sandbox
> on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny
> -msg timestamp=on 2020-07-03T18:28:51.185055Z qemu-kvm: -chardev pty,id=charserial0: char device redirected to /dev/pts/3 (label
> charserial0)

**EDIT** 04.07.2020
I just downloaded the .vhd from microsoft and converted into .qcow2 and it works well...

**EDIT** 06.07.2020
Here is the debug log of libvirt - but I can't see any error (one there is one, but I think thats not the error...). The machine is "srvvmdc".
[Dropbox Link to get the log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ri7bpuutihs7x0r/libvirtd.log?dl=0)

Comment: Why do you use SATA virtual hard drive and not [Virtio-SCSI](https://serverfault.com/a/964793/126632)?

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you for the hint. I just changed like in the link but same result...

Comment: Hm. This specific error should not happen on a fresh installation. The two most likely causes are corrupt media or failing hardware. I would get a new copy of the Server 2016 ISO image and try again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The point is i tried with 2016/2019. Every time he recognizes it as Server 2016. Yes, its the second installation with same result.

Comment: Did you re-download the ISO image?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes. Same result with "diffrent" iso's.

Comment: I would start testing the hardware, then.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I added some new informations...
Are there logs I could "study"?

Comment: You might find something interesting in `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/<vmname>.log`. Otherwise you should probably debug it like any other Windows stop code.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thx you. I shared it and will look on it...

Comment: The log doesn't show any errors.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The vhd is working...

Comment: If the VHD works then I would strongly suspect a corrupt ISO image, again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Nop. Downloaded both again and its still same error. 
Bounty in 19h...